# Problems during Flutter Android Wrappers update

Tags: android, flutter, compiler-errors, updates, arcore

I've been working in a system using flutter and the google tool ar core, from a udemy course which was using a previous version of the Android wrappers, after downloading the code from the course and trying to run it, the terminal gave me that warning:
[image: Intial warning from source code of the udemy course]

After trying to fix it by updating it using the github guide: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/wiki/Upgrading-pre-1.12-Android-projects

I had some problems 'cause I don't have the MainActivity.java, only MainActivity.kl, so I did it on the kotlin file instead.

But in the xml files the AndroidStudio gave me some errors:

At ManifestAndroid.xml

- *Attribute android:glEsVersion is not allowed here*
  on line <uses-feature android:glEsVersion="0x00030000" android:required="true" /> inside the <manifest> tag
- *Unresolved class '{applicationName}'*
  on line <application
  android:name="${applicationName}"
  >

And at the styles.xml

- *Cannot resolve symbol 'android:windowBackground'* on the line <item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/[your_launch_drawable_here]</item> and in the second call android:windowBackground too

when I try to run it the terminal gives me that error:
[image: current error]

how can I fix it and update the Android Wrappers?

Comment: can you share Androidmainfest.xml  and  styles.xml file for more clearity?

Comment: AndroidManifest.xml: https://drive.google.com/file/d/129F-6fEfCQFf3UzK_OofYcHmJ1yuEhsZ/view?usp=sharing

styles.xml: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1TTpqhTmaOfEJpCBF_N8xbhW0GsRxCyFd/view